# How to read the contents of a file onto the console using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am going back to learning js after many years off and all i want to do is read the contents of a file onto the console using Nodejs. I found the sample code. Nice and simple. I have spent over an hour trying to figure out why it will not find the file. This is sample right off the documentation and i made it exactly like the example to debug it. The absolute only difference is the name joe is replaced with my user folder.

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('/Users/gendi/test.txt', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  console.log(data)
})
```

It runs fine except it will not find test.text. no matter what. I receive the following error and no matter how i format the file path. Nothing.

```
C:\Users\gendi>node readfile.js
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\gendi\test.txt'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\gendi\\pcsSnipe\\test.txt'
}
```

You can also only pass in the file path as 'test.txt' and the exact same results come up. on the first part of the error msg the path looks formatted correctly but on the last line of the error msg it is not? Its been years.. so i know i am missing something really simple. I assure that file is there!! Thank you in advance and forgive my ineptness.

Comment: Maybe you can try the relative path like `./test.txt`, which means the text file is located same dir with your readfile.js

Comment: This returns the exact same results as passing in 'test.txt'

Comment: @genDis but exactly where is your file? in "\Users\gendi\pcsSnipe\" or in "\Users\gendi\"?

Comment: It was in both spots, id taken out the pcsSnipe to make it easier to debug and added it back later. it will work as long as you dont save the file with '.txt'

Answer (score 0):

The `fs` module requires an exact path to the file you'd like to read. A simple fix to this would be to add `__dirname` which will return the directory path along with the path of your file.

```js
// Define modules
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Read the file
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '/Users/gendi/test.txt'), 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
  if (err) // If FS returned an error
    return console.error(err); // Log the error and return
  console.log(data); // If the reading was successful, log the data
});
```

Comment: C:\Users\gendi\Users\gendi\test.txt

Comment: only works if you remove the '.txt' but works

Comment: @genDis The your file isn't actually a `txt` document, you haven't defined a file type when saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the file extention, '.txt' . Idk why it make a differnce. maybe the "." is throwing it off but it doesn't matter in this respect. Thank you